# MongoDB uniqueness amongst inner array keys

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

In mongodb I want to define a unique constraint on an inner array property but not within all documents. Can I do this using index constraints?

These two documents should be allowed:

```
{ name:'test1', properties: [ { key : 'key1', val: 'val1'}]}
{ name:'test2', properties: [ { key : 'key1', val: 'val2'}]}
```

What should not be allowed is having a document that has the same property key twice:

```
{ name:'test1', properties: [ { key : 'key1', val: 'val1'}, { key : 'key1', val: 'some other value'}]} // should fail
{ name:'test2', properties: [ { key : 'key1', val: 'val2'}, { key : 'key2', val: 'some other value'}]} // should be okay
```

any possibility to assert this on a database level?

Comment: in find query use this.

{"properties.$.key":"key1"}

Comment: thanks for linking the duplicate issue!